# Treeview or similar for parent/child menu editor Jquery ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I have a database table called Menu that basically has a MenuID, ParentID and Title.

Currently my display code create from this using a recurse function a UL / LI list.

I need, ideally free, and drap and drop control for this to allow me, in an admin page, to drag the currently loaded LI's around, and also insert a new LI.

I have found several onl/ine but they are either overkill, too complicated to setup or don't allow the drop to move into parent elements correctly

What is the best option I should take - is there a decent ideally free control out there that does this?

My site is asp.net 4 and I am ok to use jquery etc

Comment: Did you checked dynatree? http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html